# Get product variation ID from variation SKU

Tags: woocommerce

How can I get the variation ID of a variable product if I have the variation SKU?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate: [Woocommerce get Product id using product SKU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692540/woocommerce-get-product-id-using-product-sku)

Comment: Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: So (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692540/woocommerce-get-product-id-using-product-sku) it's the same procedure also for variations?

Comment: This answer works for variations https://stackoverflow.com/a/27743698/11987538